# Sql select count of sent and received

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, subquery

I need to write a query for report for sent and received transactions.

```
Status_Id      Status_dt       Status
1               4/1/2013       sent
1               4/1/2013       sent
2               4/2/2013       sent
3               4/3/2013       sent
1               4/1/2013       Received
1               4/4/2013       Received  
2               4/4/2013       received
```

The transactions which are sent on particular date can be received on any date.

From above

on 4/1/2013  transactions sent were two (for id 1) and for this id wch are sent on 4/1/2013 have received on 4/1/2013 and 4/4/2013

so o/p should be

```
dt              sent_count          received_count
4/1/2013          2                       2
```

on 4/2/2013  transactions sent were one (for id 2) and for this id wch are sent on 4/2/2013 have received on 4/4/2013

so o/p should be

```
dt              sent_count          received_count
4/2/2013          1                       1
```

on 4/3/2013  transactions sent were one (for id 3) and for this id wch are sent on 4/3/2013 has not received yet

so o/p should be

```
dt              sent_count          received_count
4/3/2013          1                       0
```

So if i run a query on 4/5/2013 the output should be:::

```
dt              sent_count          received_count
4/1/2013          2                       2 
4/2/2013          1                       1 
4/3/2013          1                       0
```

for sent count i can write query as:

```
select status_dt, count(*)
from table
where status = 'sent'
group by status_dt
```

what query should i write for received count?

Answer (score 2):

For the received, you need to join back to the sent to get the date.  If the status ids were unique, this would be the query:

```
select t.status_dt, count(*)
from table t join
     table tres
     on t.status_id = tres.status_id and
        t.status = 'sent' and
        tres.status = 'received'
group by status_dt;
```

Instead, one way is to assign a unique id:

```
select t.status_dt, count(*) as SentCount, count(tres.status_id) as ReceivedCount
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by status_id order by status_dt) as seqnum
      from table t
      where tres.status = 'sent'
     ) t join
     (select tres.*,
             row_number() over (partition by status_id order by status_dt) as seqnum
      from table tres
      where tres.status = 'received'
     ) tres
     on t.status_id = tres.status_id and
        t.seqnum = tres.seqnum
group by status_dt;
```

This unique id enumerates everything with a given `status_id` based on the date in the record (separately for sent and received).  This works, because the received are always after the sent.  So, the nth receive is always after the nth send.

If you want both SentCount and ReceivedCount in one query:

```
select t.status_dt, count(*) as SentCount, count(tres.status_id) as ReceivedCount
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by status_id order by status_dt) as seqnum
      from table t
      where tres.status = 'sent'
     ) t left outer join
     (select tres.*,
             row_number() over (partition by status_id order by status_dt) as seqnum
      from table tres
      where tres.status = 'received'
     ) tres
     on t.status_id = tres.status_id and
        t.seqnum = tres.seqnum
group by status_dt;
```

Comment: @Dems . . . There is a `status_id` field which is important.  The question refers to this as "id" as in:  "on 4/3/2013 transactions sent were one (for id 3) and for this id wch are sent on 4/3/2013 has not received yet".  So, it is `status_id` followed by `status_dt`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff... Can u help in adding one more column to above query.. this column is "received_code" which is - from the transactions which are received back has a reason code (Y). this column will reside in another table called "Codes". `code_id junct_id code_status                                                        2  101  Y`

Comment: This junction table is some thing which is in b/w codes table and status(above main) table Junction table `Junct_id status_id code_id 101 2  201`  so the end result would be dt              sent_count          received_count    received_status
4/1/2013          2                       2     0
4/2/2013          1                       1     1
4/3/2013          1                       0     0       only Status_id 2 has Received_status(code Received) Y and other ids 1 and 3 did not received any codes

Comment: @MtKr . . . You would do this by joining the code into the `tres` subquery, and then including it in the outer select.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select t1.Status_dt, 
       (select count(t2.Status) from table t2 where t2.Status='sent' and t1.Status_dt = t2.Status_dt) as sent_count,
       (select count(t2.Status) from table t2 where t2.Status='received' and t1.Status_dt = t2.Status_dt) as received_count
    from table t1 group by t1.Sattus_dt
```